# Odd CSS Loading

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am redesigning a client's website so they will be able to edit the website themselves. What I intend on doing is have the main "Front End" pages with a mix of html and php in them. The html renders the page while the php includes a external menu and grabs the content for the individual page allowing the content to be safely edited without harming the main page.

Now the problem is a have a CSS document linked that loads the menu I have two of these however whats happening is that i added some javascript to detect screen size and load a different css document if the screen is smaller then a certain size, however the website is seemingly loading half the css, it formats the menu but leaves it all in a block.

The version of the site I am working on is available at http://www.letsmine.info/Yoga

The main page without the .php extensions (To prevent the loading of the php) is http://www.letsmine.info/Yoga/index.txt

The menu is http://www.letsmine.info/Yoga/templates/menu.php

I believe the problem is javascript but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Not the issue, but it will cause you issues: You don't have an opening or closing `<ul>` or `<ol>` tag for your navigation `<li>`s. They are just naked in the `<div>`

Comment: @Wesley I know that, each <li> doesn't need a <ul> if you look at the css document http://www.letsmine.info/Yoga/css/drop.css you will understand. I may also noted i changed my javascript in a local copy to do the same thing in a similar manner, it still didn't work.

Comment: @Jason: If you look at [your validation results](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.letsmine.info%2FYoga%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) and [how to use a list in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2) you will understand.

Comment: @Wesley Hadn't got to validating it yet, code was still correct but not the valid way of doing it. I validated the code and because of my css stylesheet it hid the menu items but even hidden they were still placed wrong @Chrome Inspect Element. I will get a proper validated version up once i have fixed the css, meanwhile it is not the problem.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Rather than loading an entirely different CSS document with JavaScript, just use JavaScript to add a class to the `body` element depending on the screen size.

Comment: @Jason: Yes I do realize from looking at your page that it's not the problem, but asking people to debug what you *know* is invalid code is generally inconsiderate in my book. It should have been the first thing you tried.

Comment: @Wesley Page is now validated. Ok sorry, i considered it not to be inconsiderate as the code was still technically correct, anyway page is validated now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order of your included files.

Currently you have this:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript"> 
var screenwidth = screen.width;
if (screenwidth < 1180){
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ldrop.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />');
}
else
{
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/drop.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />');
}
</script> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>Alignment Courses</title> 
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Change it to this:

```
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/JavaScript"> 
var screenwidth = screen.width;
if (screenwidth < 1180){
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ldrop.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />');
}
else
{
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/drop.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />');
}
</script> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>Alignment Courses</title>
```

Reason? The last CSS document to be loaded takes precedence. So load the default styles first and the overriding styles last.

Comment: Doesn't completely make sense, there shouldn't be any overriding of styles as styles.css is just a default css to load and drop.css and ldrop.css are additional however I understand what you are saying. Something probably hidden in that styles.css ... I need to clean it up.

Comment: Thank you now it is up to me to clean out that styles.css!

Answer (score 0):

increase the width of #nav in style.css..

Comment: The width is not set, the elements should float themselves along side of each other. Good point though i will try setting the width as 100%

Comment: same id,s used their in drop.css and style.css, now you increased width and overrides style.css by drop its done.

Comment: Already answered, by ordering it right i override the id in the styles.css . I actually hadn't realised there was a id that was causing the problem previously. This was actually already answered but thank you anyway.